# How to prevent function in R from updating values based on last variable specified?

Tags: r, function

I have the following function:

```
stats <- function(data) {
   maxDay <<- max(data$TotalGB)
   avgDay <<- mean(data$TotalGB)
   P95Day <<- quantile(data$TotalGB, probs = (.95))
   
   return(list(paste0("The max number of GBs for is: ", maxDay), paste0("The average number of GBs is: ", avgDay), 
   paste0("The 95P GBs is: ", P95Day)))
}
```

This function returns the following results:

[[1]]
[1] "The max number of GBs for is: 700"

[[2]]
[1] "The average number of GBs is: 350"

[[3]]
[1] "The 95P GBs is: 655"

Now if I want to obtain these stats for more than 1 user, I am doing the following

```
user1 <- stats(df_1)
user2 <- stats(df_2)
```

When I do this, the value for maxDay, avgDay and P95Day will reflect the stats from user 2. What can I add so that instead of overriding the results, I could obtain the unique stats for each user.

I was thinking of just doing something like user1$avgDay but this returns in NULL

Comment: Why are you using the `<<-` operator? Are you aware of the implications?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to have a global variable because I want to use the values later in the script

Comment: Are you computing **3 times**  the same `max` as an example or do you want `max`, `mean` and quantile 95?

Comment: Setting global variables inside functions is a very bad practice. Avoid it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sorry about that. just updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something like the following? Instead of returning strings with the stats you want `paste`'d on a description, use the descriptions as list names and return a named list.

```
stats <- function(data) {
  maxDay <- max(data$TotalGB)
  avgDay <- mean(data$TotalGB)
  P95Day <- quantile(data$TotalGB, probs = 0.95)
  
  list(maxDay = maxDay, avgDay = avgDay, P95Day = P95Day)
}

user1 <- stats(df_1)
user2 <- stats(df_2)
```

And there is no need to set three global variables. Example access:

```
user1$avgDay
user2$P95Day
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me that adding the list function would be a simple solution to get around using global variables and does the job of not updating the values. This was very helpful and I will use it in the future too

Answer (score 0):

If you **REALLY** want to use `<<-` to keep updating your global variables `maxDay`, `avgDay` and `P95Day`, you can try the code below

```
maxDay <- list()
avgDay <- list()
P95Day <- list()
stats <- function(data) {
  maxDay[[length(maxDay) + 1]] <<- max(data$TotalGB)
  avgDay[[length(avgDay) + 1]] <<- max(data$TotalGB)
  P95Day[[length(P95Day) + 1]] <<- max(data$TotalGB)

  return(list(
    paste0("The max number of GBs for is: ", tail(maxDay, 1)[[1]]), paste0("The average number of GBs is: ", tail(avgDay, 1)[[1]]),
    paste0("The 95P GBs is: ", tail(P95Day, 1)[[1]])
  ))
}
```

such that

```
> stats(df1)
[[1]]
[1] "The max number of GBs for is: 87"

[[2]]
[1] "The average number of GBs is: 47.8"

[[3]]
[1] "The 95P GBs is: 84.75"


> stats(df2)
[[1]]
[1] "The max number of GBs for is: 99"

[[2]]
[1] "The average number of GBs is: 62.6"

[[3]]
[1] "The 95P GBs is: 98.1"
```

and

```
> list(maxDay, avgDay, P95Day)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 87

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 99


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 47.8

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 62.6


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
  95%
84.75

[[3]][[2]]
 95%
98.1
```

**Dummy Data**

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(TotalGB = sample(100, 10))
df2 <- data.frame(TotalGB = sample(100, 10))
```